# Remove class from a button with delay after a class has been added with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm sorry if this is a beginner question, but after hours of trying other answers here on StackOverflow, I thought I might ask the question myself.

I am currently working on a website for my project and I wanted the download button to say "Download Started" after it's been clicked to let the user know the download is working. I have achieved the following using this code:

```
<script>
function downloadBtn(dlbtn)
{
document.getElementById("download").innerHTML = dlbtn;
var element = document.getElementById("download");
element.classList.add("btn-download-started");
}
</script>
```

Which should add a class 'btn-download-started' to this link:

```
<a class="btn btn-download" href="#downloadlink"  id="download" onclick="downloadBtn('download starting...')">Download</a>
```

But I would like to have the button become active again after a few seconds in case the user accidentally stops the download etc.

How would be the best way to do this? I have also got jQuery installed currently.

Thank you in advance for your help! I really appreciate it!

Comment: how do you detect whether download is stopped?

Comment: try to use jquery ajax method for that

Comment: you can set up a simple `setTimeout` which removes the class after a fixed interval of time.

Comment: I like this approach from a UX point of view. Give the use the opportunity to load it again, but prevent accidental double downloads. Nice. For a solution, you'd probably have to use `setTimeout` to execute the piece of code for enabling the button after a couple of thousands of milliseconds.

Comment: Hi Sagar, I am actually not detecting whether the download has stopped, but rather wanted to have that feature as a redundancy, so in case anything happens the user would not need to navigate to the page again to start the download but would be able to just click the button again

Comment: Thanks @GolezTrol, I solved it quickly by adding the setTimeout function and creating a function that removes the class after the set milliseconds.

`setTimeout(RemoveClass, 3000);`

and then

`function RemoveClass() {
    $('#download').removeClass("btn-download-started");}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this for active button again after 20 Seconds.

```
<script>
  function downloadBtn(dlbtn)
  {
    document.getElementById("download").innerHTML = dlbtn;
    var element = document.getElementById("download");
    element.classList.add("btn-download-started");

    setTimeout(function () {
      element.classList.remove("btn-download-started");  
    }, 20000); // 20 Seconds
  }
</script>
```